# find pairs which sum equal to given value with o(n) complexcity

Tags: javascript

I have an Array which contains numbers. I want to find the pair of the number which sums equal to given value with o(n) complexity.

```
let data = [5,8,9,6];

var x = {};

function findSum(arr, sum){

     data.forEach(function(item){
       if(item > sum){
         return null
       }
         var diff = sum - item;
       x[item] = diff
     })

  console.log(x);
}

findSum(data, 7);
```

Working with O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity.

```
let data = [2, 4, 11, 3, 5, 8, 9, 1, 6, 5]

function findSum(arr, sum) {
  let sortArray = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });


  let findIndex = arr.indexOf(arr.find(function(item) {
    return item >= sum
  }))

  let iterateValues = sortArray.slice(0, findIndex);

  var pairs = [];
  console.log(iterateValues)
  iterateValues.forEach(function(value, index) {
    let getDiff = sum - value;
    let findDiff = iterateValues.find(function(diff, index) {
      return diff === getDiff
    });
    if (findDiff) {
      let firstPair = value.toString()
      let secondPair = findDiff.toString();
      let merge = firstPair + ',' + secondPair;
      pairs.push(merge)
    }
  })

  console.log(pairs)
}

findSum(data, 7);
```

Comment: Do you really mean `o(n)` and not `O(n)`? Do you mean `O(n²)` instead of `O(n2)`? You can use `<sup>2</sup>` in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, it takes O(n) time to find the pair whose sum is equal to given value:

```js
let data = [5,8,9,6];
var sum = 17;
var map = {};
var found = false;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  map[data[i]] = i;
}

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  if(map[sum - data[i]] && map[sum - data[i]] != i){
    found = true;
    console.log(data[map[sum - data[i]]] + " "+data[i]);
    break;
  }
}
if(!found)
  console.log("No pair found");
```

Comment: It is giving wrong pair. try with let data = [5,9,6,4];
var sum = 8;

Comment: @Carlos thanks for pointing out. I have updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Set and `for of` loop

```js
function findSum(arr, sum) {
  let set = new Set(),
      res = null;

  for (let n of arr) {
    const diff = sum - n;
    if (diff  && set.has(diff)) {
      res = [diff, n]
      break;
    }
    set.add(n);
  }

  return res ? res.join(' + ') + ' = ' + sum : 'No Matches for ' + sum

}

let data = [2, 4, 11, 3, 5, 8, 9, 1, 6, 5];
console.log(findSum(data, 6))
console.log(findSum(data, 7))
console.log(findSum(data, 8))
console.log(findSum(data, 22))
```